# RxJS Custom operator with typescript Union type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, typeerror

I have the following model :

```
export interface IModel<T> {
 exp: number,
 value: T
}
```

I want to create a custom RxJS operator such as :

```
private customOperator<U extends A | B, T extends IModel<U>>(custom: Observable<T>): Observable<U> {
    return custom.pipe(map((x: T) => x.value ));
  }
```

But I Have a type error when using it  :

```
  mySub:  = new Subject<IModel<A>>;
  myObs$: Observable<A> = this.mySub.asObservable().pipe(this.customOperator); // <== ERROR
```

The error : Can't assign type 'Observable<A | B>' to type 'Observable< A>'.

Any idea on how I could change my custom operator to avoid the issue ?

Comment: Can you tell use-case for this ? As I know the correct answer is provided to this question. But I also want to know in which use-case this is generic operator function is useful to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the operator in a factory function.

```
private customOperator<T extends IModel<U>, U extends A | B> () {
  return (custom: Observable<T>): Observable<U> =>
   custom.pipe(map((x: T) => x.value ));
}
```

And then in the pipe use the operator as a function call instead of the function ref.

```
myObs$: Observable<A> = this.mySub.asObservable().pipe(this.customOperator());
```

cheers

Comment: `pipe` already returns an observable... `asObservable` here is redundant. 

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Typescript [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) feature.

In your case the compiler complains because `myObs$` **must** be of type `Observable<A>` while your custom operator can return **either** an `Observable<A>` **or** an `Observable<B>`.

So if you want to avoid the error you need to reassure Typescript that your custom operator will **certainly** return an `Observable<A>`. This is a trick to avoid a legitimate check of the Typescript compiler, so you better be sure you are doing the right thing.

So the code should look like this

```
myObs$: Observable<A> = this.mySub.asObservable().pipe(this.customOperator) as Observable<A>;
```

or, more simply

```
myObs$ = this.mySub.asObservable().pipe(this.customOperator) as Observable<A>;
```

If you hover over `myObs$`, for instance within VSCode, you will see that the type inferred for `myObs$` is actually `Observable<A>` even if you have not specified the type (at least in this last version of the code)

**UPDATE based on @akotech response**

A better way to approach this case is what has been proposed by @akotech.

`customOperator` as coded below returns an `Observable<U>`

```
private customOperator<T extends IModel<U>, U extends A | B> () {
  return (custom: Observable<T>): Observable<U> =>
   custom.pipe(map((x: T) => x.value ));
}
```

Interestingly, at least in my case, if I do not declare the type of `myObs$` like in this line

```
myObs$ = mySub.pipe(customOperator_())
```

the type inferred for `myObs$` is `Observable<A | B>` but, at the same time, if I try something like this

```
myObs$: : Observable<B> = mySub.pipe(customOperator_())
```

I get an error from the compiler *Type 'Observable<IModel>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IModel>'*, which is correct since `mySub` notifies objects of type `IModel<A>`.

At the same time, if I try something like this

```
myObs$: : Observable<A> = mySub_A.pipe(customOperator_())
```

no error is raised by the compiler, which again is correct.

So the solution proposed by @akotech is safer than the one proposed by me.

Comment: this answer works fine, but the one suggested by @akotech seems les dangerous since i dont have to specify the type my self. Thanks a lot for your help !